# setColumnFormat Excel File

Tags: laravel

I try to format a column Date with

> $sheet->setColumnFormat(array('E' => 'dd-mm-yyyy'));

But the date still display like : yyyy/mm/dd

Someone nows how i could resolve the problem ? Thanks a lot in advance

public function build()
    {

```
    $licencies = Licencies::where('lb_assurance' , '=' , 'Lafont')
        ->leftJoin('activite_licencie' , 'activite_licencie.id' , '=' , 'licencies.activite_licencie_id')
        ->leftJoin('saisons' , 'saisons.id' , '=' , 'licencies.saison_id')
        ->leftJoin('pays' , 'pays.id' , '=' , 'licencies.pays_naissance_id')
        ->leftJoin('type_licence' , 'type_licence.id' , '=' , 'licencies.type_licence_id')
        ->leftJoin('structures' , 'structures.id' , '=' , 'licencies.structure_id')
        ->leftJoin('civilite' , 'civilite.id' , '=' , 'licencies.civilite_id')
        ->select('civilite.lb_civilite' , 'num_licence' , 'lb_nom' , 'lb_prenom' , 'dt_naissance' , 'pays.fr' ,'activite_licencie.lb_activite'  ,'saisons.lb_saison', 'lb_surclassement' ,  'structures.nom_structure' , 'lb_assurance' , 'cd_dept_naissance' , 'lb_adresse' , 'tel_fix_licencie' , 'tel_port_licencie' , 'adresse_email' , 'licencies.created_at')
        //->whereRaw('DATE(licencies.created_at) = CURRENT_DATE')
        ->get();

         $licencies->map(function($licencie) {

            $licencie['dt_naissance'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $licencie['dt_naissance'])->format('d/m/y');

        });

        $excel_file = Excel::create('DailyRecapLicencesLafont', function($excel) use ($licencies) {
        $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($licencies)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($licencies);

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your using [this package](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/), you can use one of the following date formats as per the [reference guide](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/reference-guide#formatting);

- d/m/y
- dd/mm/yy
- d/m/y
- d-m-y

`setColumnFormat` only formats the date CELL for your spreadsheet, not the value you will be inserting into it so you will also need to format the data being passed in.

You can do this in your SQL query or after you've retrieved the results, e.g;

```
$licencies = $licencies->map(function($licence) { 
    $license['DATE'] = $license['DATE']->format('d/m/y'); 

    return $license;
});
```

Obviously replacing `DATE` with the name of your date field.

Comment: Yes i use this package ! i used $sheet->setColumnFormat(array('E' => 'dd/mm/yy')); but stell don't work , what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the date instead `$licencies` formatted in `dd/mm/yy` format? When you use `->setColumnFormat()`, this is an instruction to the Excel file. You'll still need to format your date in PHP.

Comment: the format of $licencies date is yyyy/mm/dd in database

Comment: Is it yyyy/mm/dd or yyyy-mm-dd? If it's a DATE field, it should be yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: it's a date field yes sorry like yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: You can format it in SQL or you can map through the returned `Collection` and convert it via Carbon;

`$licencies  = $licencies->map(function($licence) { $license['DATE'] = $license['DATE']->format('d/m/y'); }); `

Obviously substituting `DATE` with the field you need.

Comment: i updated the code with your previous code in the post , could you see where i made a mistake ? ! i get  Call to a member function format() on string

Comment: Your date must not be automatically cast to a Carbon object. Before you call format in this case, you'll need to create a Carbon object out of your date string or use some native PHP functions to convert it's format. For Carbon, you can do something like: `$license['DATE'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $license['DATE'])->format('d/m/y');`

Comment: I get an empty excel file now ! i updated the code on the post

Comment: @MathieuMourareau when using `map`, you need to return `$licence`.